# Laravel $request->file('files') returns single uploaded file instead of many files

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload multiple images via postman.

As you can see in the screenshot, I am using form-data and I have 2 files selected for upload.
[image]

In the controller method, I just have a dumper:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd( $request->file('files') );
}
```

Here is what I get in response. 1 single file, although I uploaded 2 files, does anyone know what's wrong? Is this a postman bug or the code is wrong?
[image]

Comment: Try to change it in postman as `files[0]` `files[1]` and select files separately

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the name of the input as array.

```
<input type="file" name="attachments[]">
```

In PHP in the Controller Action do it like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('attachments')) {
    foreach ($request->attachments as $file) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`$file` is the Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile

Answer (score 0):

You can try with :

```
$request->allFiles()
```